# Multiple SELECT's in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having trouble executing multiple selects in one query. This is what I do:

```
SELECT 1 AS VisitsToday, `Datum Bezoek 1` FROM `psttodo-uit` WHERE CAST(`Datum Bezoek 1` AS DATE) = CURRENT_DATE AND PB = 1
UNION
SELECT 2 AS ConversationsToday, `Datum Bezoek 1` FROM `psttodo-uit` WHERE CAST(`Datum Bezoek 1` AS DATE) = CURRENT_DATE AND PG = 1
UNION
SELECT 3 AS PermitsToday, `Datum Bezoek 1` FROM `psttodo-uit` WHERE CAST(`Datum Bezoek 1` AS DATE) = CURRENT_DATE AND PA = 1;
```

But I get this result:

```
array (size=15)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'VisitsToday' => string '1' (length=1)
          'Datum Bezoek 1' => string '2014-02-28 08:25:34' (length=19)
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          'VisitsToday' => string '1' (length=1)
          'Datum Bezoek 1' => string '2014-02-28 08:55:34' (length=19)
      2 => 
        array (size=2)
          'VisitsToday' => string '1' (length=1)
          'Datum Bezoek 1' => string '2014-02-28 12:22:34' (length=19)
      3 => 
        array (size=2)
          'VisitsToday' => string '1' (length=1)
          'Datum Bezoek 1' => string '2014-02-28 12:28:34' (length=19)
      4 => 
        array (size=2)
          'VisitsToday' => string '1' (length=1)
          'Datum Bezoek 1' => string '2014-02-28 16:13:34' (length=19)
      5 => 
        array (size=2)
          'VisitsToday' => string '2' (length=1)
          'Datum Bezoek 1' => string '2014-02-28 08:25:34' (length=19)
      6 => 
        array (size=2)
          'VisitsToday' => string '2' (length=1)
          'Datum Bezoek 1' => string '2014-02-28 08:55:34' (length=19)
      7 => 
        array (size=2)
          'VisitsToday' => string '2' (length=1)
          'Datum Bezoek 1' => string '2014-02-28 12:22:34' (length=19)
      8 => 
        array (size=2)
          'VisitsToday' => string '2' (length=1)
          'Datum Bezoek 1' => string '2014-02-28 12:28:34' (length=19)
      9 => 
        array (size=2)
          'VisitsToday' => string '2' (length=1)
          'Datum Bezoek 1' => string '2014-02-28 16:13:34' (length=19)
      10 => 
        array (size=2)
          'VisitsToday' => string '3' (length=1)
          'Datum Bezoek 1' => string '2014-02-28 08:25:34' (length=19)
      11 => 
        array (size=2)
          'VisitsToday' => string '3' (length=1)
          'Datum Bezoek 1' => string '2014-02-28 08:55:34' (length=19)
      12 => 
        array (size=2)
          'VisitsToday' => string '3' (length=1)
          'Datum Bezoek 1' => string '2014-02-28 12:22:34' (length=19)
      13 => 
        array (size=2)
          'VisitsToday' => string '3' (length=1)
          'Datum Bezoek 1' => string '2014-02-28 12:28:34' (length=19)
      14 => 
        array (size=2)
          'VisitsToday' => string '3' (length=1)
          'Datum Bezoek 1' => string '2014-02-28 16:13:34' (length=19)
```

I also tried the following:

```
SELECT `Datum Bezoek 1` AS VisitsToday FROM `psttodo-uit` WHERE CAST(`Datum Bezoek 1` AS DATE) = CURRENT_DATE AND PB = 1
UNION
SELECT `Datum Bezoek 1` AS ConversationsToday FROM `psttodo-uit` WHERE CAST(`Datum Bezoek 1` AS DATE) = CURRENT_DATE AND PG = 1
UNION
SELECT `Datum Bezoek 1` AS PermitsToday FROM `psttodo-uit` WHERE CAST(`Datum Bezoek 1` AS DATE) = CURRENT_DATE AND PA = 1
```

But then I get this result:

```
array (size=5)
   0 => 
     array (size=1)
       'VisitsToday' => string '2014-02-28 08:25:34' (length=19)
   1 => 
     array (size=1)
       'VisitsToday' => string '2014-02-28 08:55:34' (length=19)
   2 => 
     array (size=1)
       'VisitsToday' => string '2014-02-28 12:22:34' (length=19)
   3 => 
     array (size=1)
       'VisitsToday' => string '2014-02-28 12:28:34' (length=19)
   4 => 
     array (size=1)
       'VisitsToday' => string '2014-02-28 16:13:34' (length=19)
```

What I try to get is an array with 3 keys 'VisitsToday', 'ConversationsToday' and 'PermitsToday' who each contains an array with dates selected from the database.

**UPDATE:**
Workaround with different columns like this:

```
SELECT 1 AS VisitsToday, NULL AS ConversationsToday, NULL AS PermitsToday
FROM `psttodo-uit` WHERE CAST(`Datum Bezoek 1` AS DATE) = CURRENT_DATE AND PB = 1)
UNION
SELECT NULL, 2 AS ConversationsToday, NULL
FROM `psttodo-uit` WHERE CAST(`Datum Bezoek 1` AS DATE) = CURRENT_DATE AND PG = 1)
UNION
SELECT NULL, NULL, 3 AS PermitsToday
FROM `psttodo-uit` WHERE CAST(`Datum Bezoek 1` AS DATE) = CURRENT_DATE AND PA = 1)
```

But then I get an error like this:

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the    manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')
UNION SELECT NULL, 2 AS ConversationsToday, NU' at line 2
```

Comment: and that you expect ?

Comment: What I try to get is an array with 3 keys 'VisitsToday', 'ConversationsToday' and 'PermitsToday' who each contains an array with dates selected from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to give one column multiple names - this is simply can't be done. With union, column names will be assigned in the first select.
[More info on `UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

The possible workaround is to add different columns, so it would look like this:

```
SELECT 1 AS VisitsToday, NULL AS ConversationsToday, NULL AS PermitsToday, ...
  FROM ...
UNION
SELECT NULL            , 2                         , NULL                , ...
  FROM ...
...
UNION
SELECT NULL            , NULL                      , 3                   , ...
  FROM ...
 ..;
```

Comment: This should be a comment!

Comment: So I can't do multiple selects in one query and keep them apart?

Comment: @nielsv There is no way to assing different aliases fot the same colums, but you can go other way. I'll update the answer in a minute

Comment: it would be great if you explain your answer in detail.Many people around here will find it helpful.. else your single statement should be a comment.

Comment: So I need to do 3 different queries to keep them apart?

Comment: I've updated my begin post with your code but I'm getting a syntax error, could you take a look?

Comment: remove comma here -  `NULL AS PermitsToday,
FROM`

Comment: also here `3 AS PermitsToday,
FROM`

Comment: @nielsv it seems, you facing this issue a lot, so just remeber - COMMA BEFORE `FROM` = SYNTAX ERROR

Comment: I've updated my begin post, getting a new syntax error

Comment: This is the last time - substitute all `= 1)` with `= 1`